# Multiple Files upload PHP in Ubuntu

Tags: php, file-upload, csv

I am trying to upload multiple files (tsv,csv) using PHP. The HTML and PHP script is written below. It works for me when running with XAMPP on Windows. However, on Ubuntu,when trying upload 2 files at a time (one is tsv, the other is csv) I can only upload one file at a time, but not two. I am not sure what the reasons are but it seems that there is something needed to be done with the server settings.

The code below won't work if I upload both tsv and csv but it works with other file types.

```
<form action='' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type='file' name='usrfile[]'/>
<input type='file' name='usrfile[]'/>
<input type='submit' name='submit'/>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    for($i=0;$i<=1;$i++){
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["usrfile"]["tmp_name"][$i],"upload/" . $_FILES["usrfile"]["name"][$i]);//upload the ecwave file to the upload/ folder    
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Lovely file injection vulnerability... enjoy having your server trashed because you're allowing users to upload any file they want, and put it ANYWHERE on your server they want.

Comment: this is just a part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

[Make a look at the manual.](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php)

There is a max_file_uploads setting, which restricts the number of allowed files per form.

Comment: Thank you but the current max_file_uploads is already set to 20. The problem is tsv and csv files cannot be uploaded at the same time. Other file types seems to have no problems with the script.